# Setting FlowDirection for all WPF windows in application

Tags: c#, wpf, user-interface

I'm working on multilanguage application so I need to set flow direction for all my application windows when the end user change the UI language.

I create a class than must be do the job:

```
public static void UILanguage(string UICulture)
{
        ((App)Application.Current).LanguageSwitcher(UICulture);

        Window.FlowDirectionProperty.OverrideMetadata(
            typeof(Window),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture.TextInfo.IsRightToLeft ?
                FlowDirection.RightToLeft :
                FlowDirection.LeftToRight));
}
```

Then I call the method `UILanguage` when application startup:

```
LanguageSwitcher.UILanguage("en-GB");
```

When I run the application, I got the following error : **PropertyMetadata is already registered for type 'Window'.'**

Any help

Comment: Consider creating attached behavior to monitor for language change (event in your custom class) and to set flow (and maybe more). Then you only need to use it once in every custom window xaml.

Comment: OverrideMetadata is not supposed to be used like this. You need a different approach, maybe iterate over all Windows in `Application.Current.Windows`.